# Quantmod Error 'cannot open URL'

Tags: r, quantmod

I started to experience an error today with the quantmod package. Anybody else have the same error when running this code (or requesting symbols in general)?

`library(quantmod)
getSymbols("CPIAUCNS",src="FRED")`

Error:
`Error in download.file(paste(FRED.URL, "/", Symbols[[i]], "/", "downloaddata/",  : 
  cannot open URL 'http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/series/CPIAUCNS/downloaddata/CPIAUCNS.csv'`

The URL itself works fine.

Comment: Please show actual URLs your loop is generating.

Comment: By url i meant the `http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/series/CPIAUCNS/downloaddata/CPIAUCNS.csv` the error generates. If you insert it into a browser, a csv file will download.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Maybe FRED changed something? I'm not having any problem with yahoo, for example

Comment: @chandler thank you for your response. I am encountering the same issue. Glad I am not alone.

Comment: It works for me: ‘0.4.4’ version.

Comment: I am running 0.4.4 version as well, but it does not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another (temporary) solution is to call one of the following before the actual `getSymbols` script:

`options(download.file.method="libcurl")`
or
`options(download.file.method="wget")`
or
`options(download.file.method="wininet")`

The first option works for me (on Mac).
Thanks Paul Gilbert from [Rmetrics](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/getSymbols-for-FRED-in-quantmod-has-stopped-working-td4709356.html) (bottom post)

Answer (score 7):

FRED changed the URL scheme from http:// to https://. I'm working on determining a patch that will work on all platforms. The current code still works for me on Windows if `--internet2` is set.

On unix-alikes, one potential solution is to add `method="curl"` or `method="wget"` to the `download.file` call in `getSymbols.FRED`.

Comment: on windows add: setInternet2(use = TRUE) before getSymbols("CPIAUCNS",src="FRED")

Answer (score 2):

The problem appeared yesterday:
`Cannot verify certificate for stlouisfed.org issued by GoDaddy.`

A workaround:

`temp = tempfile()`

`download.file(url="http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/series/DAAA/downloaddata/CPIAUCNS.csv",destfile=temp, method="libcurl")`

`result <- read.csv(temp,na.string=".")`

I hope having to use this fix is temporary.

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution that works for me, assuming you trust FRED's SSL certificate.

All you need to do is adding the following extra line of code before executing getSymbols:

```
options(download.file.method = "wget", download.file.extra = c("--no-check-certificate"))
```

Example:

```
getSymbols("M2", from = start_date, to = end_date, src = "FRED")
```

[1] "M2"

```
str(M2)
```

An ‘xts’ object on 1980-11-03/2015-10-05 containing:
  Data: num [1:1823, 1] 1591 1593 1596 1597 1596 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr "M2"
  Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC
  xts Attributes:
List of 2
 $ src    : chr "FRED"
 $ updated: POSIXct[1:1], format: "2015-10-21 11:01:39"