# `quantmod`'s `getSymbols.FRED` not working as expected

Tags: r, quantmod

The following lines are from `quantmod`'s manual (p54):

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols('CPIAUCNS',src='FRED')
```

returns:

```
Error in download.file(paste(FRED.URL, "/", Symbols[[i]], "/", "downloaddata/",  : 
  cannot open URL 'http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/series/CPIAUCNS/downloaddata/CPIAUCNS.csv'
```

How to fix this?

(using latest version of both `R` and `quantmod`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `https://` for the URL instead.

Comment: thanks, but how do you do this? I mean in practice

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31197196/3285115