# Cannot get FRED data via R

Tags: r, quantmod

I am getting an error when I download data from FRED:

```
Error in download.file(paste(FRED.URL, "/", Symbols[[i]], "/", "downloaddata/",  : 
  cannot open URL 'http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/series/RU2000PR/downloaddata/RU2000PR.csv'
```

Here is what I run:

```
library("quantmod")
getSymbols("RU2000PR", src='FRED')
```

When I manually paste the URL it will download the file...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31188023/quantmod-error-cannot-open-url