# Shiny tutorial lesson 6: getting error

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to run the shiny tutorial 6 app, from shiny-Rstudio website. The url is :

http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson6/

While trying to run the app, I am getting below error:

```
Error : Failed to download file. Error message:
cannot open URL 'https://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/series/CPIAUCNS/downloaddata/CPIAUCNS.csv'
```

I am new to shiny and do not understand this error.

Comment: Post your code, where do you receive this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer in other thread in stack-overflow:

[Quantmod Error 'cannot open URL'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31188023/quantmod-error-cannot-open-url)

The code that should be used to run the app for lesson 6 is:

```
library(shiny)
options(download.file.method="libcurl")#This fixed the error
runApp("stockVis")
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have saved `server.R`, `ui.R` and `helpers.r` in a folder named "stockVis". If it's ok, you could try to specify the path of the app, like this :

```
library(quantmod)
runApp("D:/mydocuments/stockVis")
```