# read FRED data into csv or R

Tags: r, csv, finance, economics

Related to [Quantmod Error 'cannot open URL'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31188023/quantmod-error-cannot-open-url) .  How can I write a program to download FRED data in csv format, e.g., for further processing in R, perl, etc.?

answer to follow.

Answer (score 1):

I put up a simple gateway site in `http://fred-csv.info` that shows how to invoke a URL which makes loading FRED data in csv format easy.  That is, it just invokes a URL

```
$ curl http://www.ivo-welch.info/fredwrap?symbol=GDPC1
```

that returns the appropriate csv file.  No programming required.  Such URL requests are easy to embed in R or other languages with something like

```
> library(RCurl)
> mytdata <- getURL(paste0('http://www.ivo-welch.info/fredwrap?symbol=', 'GDPC1'))
> d <- read.csv(textConnection(mytdata), header=T)
```

where GDPC1 is the mnemonic name of just one (out of their 500,000 data seres).  hope this helps avoid wasted programming time for others.